# There is one video which plays but sound not coming in Mac

Tags: macos, audio, video, quicktime, mediaplayer

I have one video which is playing well in Windows machine and also sound is coming. But, while I am playing same video on Mac or iPad, sound is not coming. In my Mac and iPad, I have tried other videos which are playing and also sound is coming.

In QuickTime Player, if I view details of the video which does not give sound, I cannot find AAC, whereas in other video, I find it.

Here is the screenshots:

> Screenshot 1 shows the details of video that gives sound:

[image]

> Screenshot 2 shows the details of video that does not give sound:

[image]

What may be the reason for it? These videos are given by my client and both are giving sound in Windows machine but one of the 2 video not giving sound in Mac or iPad.

Comment: Although I'm not really answering the question of why you have this problem, if you really want to play this file, install VLC on your Mac and iPad, and it will work for you.

Comment: Thanks Bill..That's right becuase QuickTime will only support AAC and MP3 Audio CODECS.

Answer (score 1):

Mac and iOS only supports `AAC` and `MP3` Audio CODEC, while my video has `MPEG Audio layer 1/2` Audio CODEC. So, while converting/compressing this video, my client has selected audio CODEC to default rather than `AAC`.

Here are difference between those two video files:

> Screenshot 1 shows the CODEC details of video that gives sound:

[image]

> Screenshot 2 shows the CODEC details of video that does not give sound:

[image]